# Int inadverantly cast to string behind my back

Tags: c#

This was originally a problem with Crystal Reports but I tracked down the issue to a single line of code:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["CurrentScheduleFields"].Rows)
    if (dr["MY_FIELD"].ToString() == string.Empty)
        dr["MY_FIELD"] = 0;
```

I am using an Oracle database. The field is actually a Numeric(2). We are using straight ADO.NET and no Nullable types in this case. In one case, the field in question has a value of an int and the above line of code is fine. The other case, the value of the field is DBNull.Value, and the above or something is converting the 0 to "0" ( a string).

`dr` is *not* a `DataReader    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["CurrentScheduleFields"].Rows)

Does anyone know why?

My browser is not letting me click on the Add Comments, so I am adding stuff here. Why can't I do if (dr["MY_FIELD"] == DBNull.Value)
                        dr["MY_FIELD"] = 0;
the debugger hits that and converts to a string with a value of "0", not 0. I guess the first answer handles this, "So the problem may be that the first "MY_FIELD" is null, convincing ADO.NET that the type for that column is a string." So it's now string with DBNull.Value in it?

My browser is locked down. I can't click on anything except edit this but:
ANSWER: Handle this on the Crystal side by changing the formula to handle a string for this value and not an int. It works!

Comment: It looks like `dr` is some sort of `DataReader`.

Comment: @Sam: I think it's very unlikely that this code is setting the field to "0", unless Oracle does the conversion itself.

Comment: Maybe it is [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx)? What does the debugger say when you set a (conditional) breakpoint and inspect the variable?

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: it is clearly something that implements `IDataRecord` and probably `IDataReader`. I wouldn't be surprised if it's an `OracleDataReader`.

Comment: How are you verifying that the value is converted to a string?

Comment: What is `dr["MY_FIELD"].GetType().Name` ?

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, when dealing with DataTable, I've seen it try to "guess" at the type of a column based on the value in that column in the first row in your set.  So the problem *may* be that the first "MY_FIELD" is null, convincing ADO.NET that the type for that column is a string.

You may want to set the schema for your DataTable before you try to load it.